# Вычетание в python

Tags: python

В общем, мне надо вычесть из `a` `a1`. Только не через списки, я нашёл функцию `remove`, но это для списков.

```py
n = int(input("Кол-во "))
a = ''
h = ''
for i in range(n):
    a = a + (input())
    a1 = min(a)
    h = a1 + h
    # тут надо a[a1]
print (h)
```

Пример входных данных:
`n = 3`

`2`
`7`
`1`

Вывод:
`127`

Comment: ваша задача - удалить минимальный элемент что ли? вы скажите конкретно что должен делать ваш код

Comment: Ну не совсем, это метод сортировки от меньшего к большему, тоесть в цикле оно каждый раз минимальное будет ставить назад а с переменной а вырезать её

Comment: Код должен сортировать от меньшего к большему

Comment: бррррр - а на выходе список должен быть? код какой-то вообще неработоспособный

Comment: ну если без того что после # оно всё работает, на выходе не список должен быть, вот от моей программы мне нужна какая то команда которая вырезает заданный объект - a из a1

Comment: можно пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: входные данные n = 3 
3 6 2
236

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста это в свой вопром (это можно сделать с помощью кнопки [edit])

Comment: уже добавил ...

Comment: Интересная задачка... Для строк можно использовать replace. Код можно изменять только там где # другой трогать нельзя? очень уж смущает предыдущая строка.

Comment: если как то понятно для новичка исправить то можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```py
n = int(input("Кол-во "))
a = ''
h = ''
for i in range(n):
    a = a + (input())

for i in a:
    a1 = min(a) # получаем наименьший элемент в a
    h += a1 # записываем его в (h=h+a1). Любые последующие просто добавляем в конец строки
    a= a.replace(a1, "") # Удаляем текущий наименьший элемент в `a` и повторяем цикл пока в `a` есть данные. 

print (h)
```

из минусов что не обрабатывает ввод двойных чисел. (10 15 и тд) но при Вашем вводе нет возможности их отделить в `a`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Можете только мне еще объяснить почему после h += a1 ?

Comment: Добавил коменты в код